# function for finding the nearest number of a given value

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

I was practicing with function and I encountered this problem. I would be grateful if someone gave me pointers on how to solve it.

Python function given below in a monotonically increasing
function in N. Find the N value that makes G(N) as close 124599 as
possible. You may use trial and error or you may use a for loop

```
def G(N):
  a, b = 7, 9
  while N > 2:
    N = N - 1
    a = b
    b = int(0.83*a + 0.83*b)
  return b
```

I have tried to use for in range loop
but the numbers I get are too small compare to the given number.

Comment: if the function is monotonically increasing, then a simple binary search will get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point here is that the function is *monotonically increasing*. That means that in between two points, the function can only go up.

So if `G(A) < target` and `G(B) > target` then, and only then, the answer we seek will be between `A` and `B`, and it will be there only once.

Knowing this, all we need to do is evaluate `G()` at the midpoint between `A` and `B`, and compare that result to the target to narrow down the range until we stop making progress. aka: a binary search.

Here's a rather verbose (for clarity) way to do that:

```
def monotonic_closest(Func, target, integral):
  # First, find points below and above the target
  bottom = -1
  while G(bottom) > target:
    bottom *= 2

  top = 1
  while G(top) < target:
    top *= 2

  # Now narrow down the range until we stall.
  while True:
    # Get a halfway point
    if integral:
      mid = (top + bottom) // 2
    else:
      mid = (top + bottom) / 2
    
    if G(mid) > target:
      # We are stalling, stop
      if top == mid:
        return mid
      
      # narrow the range
      top = mid
    else:
      # We are stalling, stop
      if bottom == mid:
        return mid
    
      # narrow the range
      bottom = mid




result = monotonic_closest(G, 124599, integral=True)
```

Depending on the shape of the function, there are other methods that can converge faster, but the simply binary search has the advantage of being *consistent*, no matter what the function is.

Comment: This gives a result of `N=20` `G(20)` is `75061`, but `G(21)` is closer at `124601`

Comment: @Mark, well, it gives `20.000000...4` for which `G(N)` is the same value as `G(21)`, so it's technically as valid. I'll refine the answer so that it can work on integers as well in case that's what OP wants.

Comment: Ha! Good point. Given that the original `G` is based on integer values of N, I wonder if just swapping out you division operator: `(top + bottom) // 2` would work?

Comment: @Mark it certainly does :) Thanks for the reminder for that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things that comes to mind when dealing with this sort of problem is a binary search. At the moment, there is no upper limit to the search space, so the first step would be to find one. Going by powers of ten, that would be:

```
guess = 1
target = 124599
while G(guess) < target:
    guess = 10*guess
```

From there, you can set your upper limit to `guess` and do a binary search:

```
lower = 0
upper = guess
while True:
    difference = upper - lower
    if difference < 2:
        break
    midpoint = lower + difference//2
    if G(midpoint) > target:
        upper = midpoint
    if G(midpoint) < target:
        lower = midpoint
```

However, you can also use math to solve it. Just before the line `b = int(0.83*a + 0.83*b)`, `a` has been set to `b`. So this is just `b = int(0.83*b + 0.83*b)`, which is equivalent to `b = int(1.66*b)`. If it weren't for the `int` part, this would be just be multiplying `b` by `1.66` over and over again, so we would get `b*1.66^k`. If we take the initial value of `9`, we get `9*1.66^k = 12599`, or `1.66^k = 1399.888888888889`. Next, we can take the log of both sides. This gets us `k log(1.66) = log( 1399.888888888889)`, or k = `log(1399.888888888889)/log(1.66) = 14.29`.

With the first method, I got 21. The second number is off because `G(N)` doesn't get started until `N` is greater than `2`, and it grows slower than 1.66x at the beginning because of the rounding of `int`. If you were to start later in the series, such as at 10, you'd get

G(10) = 473
G(k) = 124599
G(k)/G(10) = 263.4
log(263.4)/log(1.66) = 10.997

Rounding to the nearest integer, this would tell you that the number you're looking for is 11 greater than 10, or 21.